# file_get_contents with context to change user agent didn't work

Tags: php

I'am trying to get the read and like number of an page.

[image]

The url is: https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/NPavBeHc8VdWXeSL6kfLRg
(you must activate a mobile user agent to see read and like number. There are at the bottom left of the page.
You must refresh the page.)

The problem is that read and like number are hidden when isn't a mobile user agent that visit the site.

So i tried to use file_get_contents() with a context that send user agent with http as other stackoverflow post said. But didn't work :(.

There is my code:

```html
$url = 'https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/NPavBeHc8VdWXeSL6kfLRg';


$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'header'  => 'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; HM NOTE 1LTEW Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 MicroMessenger/6.0.0.54_r849063.501 NetType/WIFI',
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

print_r($result);
```

I also tried to modify the php.ini with

> user_agent= "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Comment: there no read and like number on that page even using a mobile user agent.

Comment: @PedroLobito , I posted the image. Just use the F12 on Chrome or Firebug on firebox. Chose a mobile et refresh the page. You will se them at the bottom left.

Comment: Nop, it's not happening. It must have some sort of geoip restriction. https://screenpresso.com/=NUc1f

Comment: strange, it's still working with me. Can you try with this longer url, and refresh ?

Comment: Edit, the longer url is too long. And stackover flow does not allow shotten url :(

Comment: post it on paste bin and share the link

Comment: @PedroLobito there is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/V4SAXi2M

Comment: `'header' => 'User-Agent: Mozilla...'` or  `'user_agent' => 'Mozilla...'`

Comment: @Deadooshka i replaced, didn't show up likes and reads. I edited the pose with news codes

Comment: I can't get the bottom element with this user-agent. Open browser's f12/network and trace up this content. Maybe you have to dig into a js-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

From [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php):

> `user_agent string`
>
> Value to send with `User-Agent:` header. This value will only be used
>   if user-agent is not specified in the `header` context option above.

If you opt for `header`, you need to set the header name as well, not just the value!

Comment: some thing like this ? $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'header'  => 'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; HM NOTE 1LTEW Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 MicroMessenger/6.0.0.54_r849063.501 NetType/WIFI',
    )
);